# Как писать на "ты", на "вы" — с прописной или строчной, в кавычках или без?

Tags: пунктуация, местоимения

1. **Мне очень трудно с вами быть на вы, может, перейдем на ты.** (?)
2. **К начальнику обращаться только на вы.** (?)

Comment: Возьмите любой словарь, найдите статью "Ты" - наверняка там это будет. Я нашла в двух словарях первых попавшихся с полки: в Толковом словаре русского языка Ожегова и Шведовой (Москва. "АЗЪ".1995) и во Фразеологическом словаре русского литературного языка Фёдорова (Новосибирск. "Наука". Сибирская издательская фирма РАН. 1995)

Comment: Ответ плохо сформулирован. Напишите, что именно вы нашли в словарях.

Answer (score 3):

В нацкорпусе примеров с кавычками очень много, и это понятно. До недавнего времени написание без кавычек сложно было представить. Но в современном русском языке появилась тенденция к отказу от кавычек в этих сочетаниях.

*Максим перешел на ты потому, что глупый враг уважения не достоин.*

***На вы* и *на ты*** - ***это устойчивые выражения, употребляемые настолько часто, что отпала необходимость использовать кавычки в их написании***.

Подтверждение здесь [Как правильно пишется на ты](http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/na-ti/?q=532&n=72421)

Comment: Кусок текста на веб-сайте без отсылки к первоисточнику не может быть подтверждением правила. Даже если коллектив сайта –
 это "_заслуженные учителя русского языка и литературы, преподаватели крупных российских вузов, соискатели ученых степеней, лингвисты и литературоведы, представители различных филологических дисциплин_"

Comment: А что по поводу прописной? Грамота пишет: "на Вы" (Вопрос № 246287).

Answer (score 2):

В выражении перейти на ты/вы не нужно заключать местоимение в кавычки.

[Словари.ру](http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=1168) [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%A2%D1%8B&start=30)

Comment: не могли бы вы более точно указать раздел и место в справочнике, где описана данная норма? Сам искал, не могу найти.

Comment: благодарю за ссылку. Но я смотрю пункт 8 и вижу кавычки... Жаль, тут нельзя приложить скриншот.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXnqDBrePUAhWDPBQKHflDAngQFggzMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Forfogrammka.ru%2F%25D1%2582%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BF%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B3%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D1%2584%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0%2F%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B8%25D1%2588%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B5_%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B2%25D1%258B%25D1%2587%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B8%2F&usg=AFQjCNESBF4PqWBDv_mdFxL8-47U2PkcvQ

Comment: Эту статью я уже читал и в ней тоже нет точной ссылки на норму. Есть лишь 'список литературы' в конце, в которой я также не нашел этого правила.

Comment: Да, при ответе я руководствовался этой рекомендацией. Но я уже обратился к ним. Посмотрим, что они скажут.

Comment: P.S. Очень жаль, что вы удалили свой комментарий со ссылкой. Теперь мой второй комментарий "повис в воздухе", кто будет читать - не поймет.

Comment: Vlad, его я удалил только потому, что там действительно выражение было в кавычках. Я не заметил. Но как только там дадут ответ, я вам обязательно отвечу.

Comment: Vlad, они ответили и дали ссылку на Грамоту.ру. Но рекомендации Грамоту.ру противоречат друг другу. В ответе лучше дать ссылку на Грамоту.ру. кстати, и сотрудники института русского языка тоже дают рекомендацию не заключать в кавычки это выражение.

Comment: Ну что ж, теперь ясно, что история темная :)